# can't launch CoqIde

Tags: coq, formal-verification, formal-methods, coqide

Everything is fine until I changed the preferences -> Externals -> coqtop in CoqIde and then I found myself in trouble launching CoqIde as the picture shows. It seems that I wrote the wrong path in the coqtop. I have tried to reinstall the coqplatform and It seems useless. So how can I restart my CoqIde?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the user configuration files of CoqIDE are in:

```
C:\Users\<Yourname>\AppData\Local\coq
```

Please note that AppData is typically a hidden folder, so you can't see it. Either enable display of hidden folders in file explorer or use the console.

You need to delete the file `coqiderc` in this folder (or fix it with a text editor).